# Controlling system resources with nice and ionice

Tags: ros, roslaunch, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to run nodes with high priority for both cpu time and file i/o time. As found in [roslaunch documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB), we can use a `launch-prefix` to run `nice`, like this example for `rosserial`:

```
<node name="rosserial" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py"
    launch-prefix="nice -n -5 ionice -c2 -n0"
    respawn="true" >
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyS0" />
    <param name="baud" value="115200" />
</node>
```

This works if I run `nice -n 10` (or any nice value above 0), but requires superuser privileges if I want to increase the priority of the process using a negative nice value. However, this leads into a slew of [nastiness](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/?answer=189462#post-id-189462) with the superuser (e.g. `rospy` not existing on the `PYTHONPATH`), even if I use passwordless sudo.

Am I missing some typical way `nice` is used to elevate process priorities in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262613/controlling-system-resources-with-nice-and-ionice/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2017-05-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-26**:
I think the 'nicest' way to do something like this is to give the user `roslaunch`ing the *capability* to set process priorities / niceness, but that might be involved. You could try and see whether `sudo -E` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In looking for answers to my question, it seems like the approach I'm going for is wrong, as setting a user process to a negative nice value can lead to some conflict with system processes. Better to limit other user-space processes' resource usage than to increase a single user process's priority into the system process space.

That said, if anyone else is trying to do this in the future, it should be possible to add a rule in [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) to allow user-space procresses to have negative nice values without sudo (but I haven't tested this.)

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2017-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1